# Limits of indicator functions tending to infinity

Tags: limits

Consider a function whose domain is set of all integers and it is defined as f(x)= 1 for all integral values of x(and it is not defined for fractional values).

What is
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}  f(x)\ ?
$$

---

It seems that the answer should be 1 but think about other periodic functions having 2 elements in range. For example, what does Dirichlet function tends to when x tends to infinity? We say that it is oscillating at 0 and 1. Similarly, can't we say in our case that f(x) is oscillating at 1 and "nothing" since infinity can be both integral or fractional?

Answer (score 2):

A part of the riddle is what kind of limit you are taking. If your notion of limit is analogous to a limit of sequences, it would be well-defined here and just like if a sequence $a_0, a_1, \ldots$ can be defined by taking $a_0 = a_1 = \ldots = 1$, with
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 1,
$$
so too you can think of this "discrete" notion of limit applied to your function, yielding $1$ in the limit.

---

One could also try to apply the continuous limit, in which case it would not exist since $f(x)$ is undefined where $x \not \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I hope that such a question does not come in exam, because most probably they will not mention whether they are talking about sequences notion or continuous notion

Comment: but there is a problem. Consider the function f(x)=x where the domain of f(x) is set of all rational numbers. I am considering the continuous limit which you were talking about, according to which limit of f(x) should not exist at any rational since there irrational numbers also in the neighborhood of any rational number where the function is not defined. This also means that f(x) is everywhere discontinuous, but the irony is that I can draw the curve without lifting the pen. Is not it wierd?

Comment: @Ritil since the function is not continuous _anywhere_, there is literally not a point that you can "draw without lifting a pen," since drawing without lifting a pen is a notion for continuity.